# Limiting Checkbox Selection using JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

We have a requirement to Limit the user Selection of a checkbox to a maximum. For example, we read different car models from a database and place them on a form for a user to select a maximum of two car models for further processing. we are using the following code segments (Sample codes Only):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function KeepCount() 
{   
    var total=0;
    for (var i=0; i < document.car_form.model_selection.length; i++) 
    {
        if(document.car_form.model_selection[i].checked) {
            total =total + 1;
        }
        if (total > 2) {
            alert('Pick Just One Please')
            document.car_form.model_selection[i].checked = false ;
            return false;
        }
    }
} 
</script> 

<form action="car_model.php" method="post" name="car_form" id="car_form">

<?php
$q10 = "SELECT ..."
$r10 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q10); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($r10) > 0) {    
    while ($row10 = mysqli_fetch_array($r10, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {
        echo '<p class="normal_text"><input type="checkbox" name="model_selection[]" value="' . $row10['model_id'] . '" onclick="return KeepCount()"; />' . $row10['car_model_name'] . '</p></br>';
    }
}
?>    
</form>
```

This code however does not work as even if a user Selects more than 2 models, no warning is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function KeepCount() {                    
                var inputTags = document.getElementsByName('model_selection[]');                    
                var total = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < inputTags.length; i++) {

                    if (inputTags[i].checked) {                      
                            total = total + 1;
                    }

                    if (total > 2) {
                        alert('Pick Just One Please')
                        inputTags[i].checked = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
  </script>
```

Problem with above code is model_selection not array so it throw error undefined "length" property.

Comment: it did work - thanks. We have now Another Issue 1) whereby, the form extends over a few pages and there is is a need to remember the checkkbox selection before the form Submit button is pressed. i.e., when a user navigates across different pages of a form, still the user should be able to See his checkbox Selection. How to Achieve this please. Issue-2: how to enable CheckAll and Reset Selection please.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is because your dom path is wrong to get the checkboxes. This code should work iterating though all checkboxes.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function KeepCount()  { 
    var elements = document.getElementsByName("model_selection[]");
    var total = 0;
    for(var i in elements) {
        var element = elements[i];
        if(element.checked) total++;
        if(total>2) {
            alert("pick one please");
            element.checked = false;
            return false;    
        }
    }
  } 
  </script>
  <form action="car_model.php" method="post" name="car_form" id="car_form">
  <p class="normal_text"><input type="checkbox" name="model_selection[]" value="id1" onclick="return KeepCount()"></p>
  <p class="normal_text"><input type="checkbox" name="model_selection[]" value="id2" onclick="return KeepCount()"></p>
  <p class="normal_text"><input type="checkbox" name="model_selection[]" value="id3" onclick="return KeepCount()"></p>
  <p class="normal_text"><input type="checkbox" name="model_selection[]" value="id4" onclick="return KeepCount()"></p>
  <p class="normal_text"><input type="checkbox" name="model_selection[]" value="id5" onclick="return KeepCount()"></p>
  <p class="normal_text"><input type="checkbox" name="model_selection[]" value="id6" onclick="return KeepCount()"></p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```